# Java - Assigning an array to an object reference

Tags: java, arrays, object

How come I can assign an array to an object reference

```
Object x = (Object) new int[] { 1, 2, 3 };// no error
Object y = new int[] { 1, 2, 3 };//no error
```

Do java arrays inherit from Object similar to classes?

I expected this to give me a compile time error.

Doing this:

```
System.out.println(x.toString() + " " + x.getClass().getName() + " " + x.getClass().getTypeName());
```

Results in:

```
[I@15db9742 [I int[]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Do java arrays inherit from Object similar to classes?

Yes, because arrays are instances of classes, just like other objects. This is why they have `hashCode` and `toString` and `getClass`, they inherit them from `Object`.

From [JLS§10.1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-10.html#jls-10.1):

> The supertype relation for array types is not the same as the superclass relation. The direct supertype of `Integer[]` is `Number[]` according to §4.10.3, but the direct superclass of `Integer[]` is `Object` according to the `Class` object for `Integer[]` (§10.8). This does not matter in practice, **because `Object` is also a supertype of all array types**.

*(my emphasis)*

And (perhaps relevant) from [JLS§10.2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-10.html#jls-10.2):

> A variable of array type holds a reference to an object.

Answer (score 3):

According to [official tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-10.html) :

> In the Java programming language, arrays are objects (§4.3.1), are
>   dynamically created, and may be assigned to variables of type Object
>   (§4.3.2). All methods of class Object may be invoked on an array.

Answer (score 0):

Well all arrays(primitive arrays or Object arrays) are Objects.